# is there any way to prevent illegitimate locations on android/ios?

Tags: android, security, gps, location

I'm thinking about developing an app for android or ios, but the whole purpose of the app is a game based on locations, like foursquare. the problem is that the game would be very unfair if people could spoof their locations with fake ones, and I was wondering if there is any way to make sure that the locations they give me are where they actually are.

Is this possible in any way, or will I just have to trust the user that they are using their real gps location, and not a hacked software to change it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: thats what people do :-( you'd have to get into heuristics like "If person A was in London yesterday they can't be in Egypt today" which is obviously flawed as well. Someone may have a better idea!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880232/disable-check-for-mock-location-prevent-gps-spoofing ?

Comment: I think a combination of the answers provided in Tim's link, plus what Blundell suggested, would be the most appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general code/API solution for iOS and Android.

One thing that makes this difficult is that, even if the device API guaranteed accurate location, Android devices can be "rooted" and iOS devices can be "jailbroken" allowing the end user to modify the API implementation.