# Detect location spoofing in android?

Tags: android, gps

Is there a solid way to detect that location given by GPS is a spoofed ( If some mock location has been set to the device in background ?

There are apps in the market , which can provide fake location to the GPS .

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en

Rooted users can run Fake GPS without setting "Allow mock location" option.

Is there a way to detect spoofed location ?

I have posted solution here, since It been closed by few people who were unware about this .
[Disable / Check for Mock Location (prevent gps spoofing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880232/disable-check-for-mock-location-prevent-gps-spoofing/16776891#16776891)

Comment: In Developer phone you can make GPS location as spoof . There are app in the market to sppof the GPS .I want to detect that .

Comment: First install the app and see the result of LocationManager.

Comment: You could check the location from other sources, wifi/mobile base stations and if the difference is above a certain maximum assume it's fake.

Comment: If wifi is not available and spoofed location is similar to mobile then how to detect ?

Comment: But I don't understand why this question has been downvoted ? If answer is not known or question is not clear , then It can be discussed more in comments ...But putting vote down means question is invalid..but here this is not the case..!!

Comment: it was downvoted by people who did not understand what spoofing is

Comment: Thanks AlexWien ...Stackoverflow community needs more people like you..:)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880232/disable-check-for-mock-location-prevent-gps-spoofing

Comment: @IceMAN This is a proper question. It is not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical. It should not have been collapsed because you did not understand it.

Comment: I have found the solution for the same and posted here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880232/disable-check-for-mock-location-prevent-gps-spoofing/16776891#16776891

Comment: This should be reopened and if answered somewhere else should be marked as duplicate. But surely not closed

Comment: Agreed; I think it's pretty obvious what was being asked