# Fake GPS locations persist after disabling

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, android-fusedlocation, google-location-services

On our Android app we need to detect when users have been providing us with fake locations.  Once we disable the fake location app ("Fake GPS"), the Fused Location Provider keeps sending us the old location, but without the mock location key on it.

Is this a known bug?  Is there any way to detect if those new locations were from the fake provider?

We are using a Nexus 6P with 6.0.1 to test

Answer (score 0):

When you stop Fake GPS app, the mock location is being stored for GPS provider. And don't assume real location will receive whenever you press the stop button. You can do something like this after stop.

- Enable GPS(if disabled)
- Make location request for GPS (open google map)
- GPS icon will start blinking, just wait (but not indoor)

> Is there any way to detect if those new locations were from the fake provider?

For not-rooted devices, it's possible to understand whether a location is mock or not. Look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880232/disable-check-for-mock-location-prevent-gps-spoofing)

Answer (score 0):

Since API 18 release, [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object has the method [isFromMockProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider()) to check whether the location is from MockProvider.

```
public static boolean isMockLocation(Location location) {
     return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 && location != null && location.isFromMockProvider();
}
```

On API 17 and below, mock locations are detected using [Settings.Secure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).

```
public static Boolean isMockLocationEnabled(Context context) {
     return !Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0");
}
```

The general pattern with mock locations is that bearing, speed, accuracy, altitude and time interval (between consecutive data points) are hard-coded values. But some times [isFromMockProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider()) is unreliable for some location means they are not tagged as mock location. But these locations have much poorer accuracy than the other mock location readings. Most of the Fake GPS send all location with fixed accuracy. But when you disable the Fake GPS, the untagged location might show up because of the outcome of fusion logic of FusedLocation API.

So what you can do to detect these locations

- Keep the most recent detected mock location.
- Calculate the distance between last mock location and current untagged location.
- If calculated distance is less than 1 KM then reject it.
- Remove last stored mock location if you have received atleast 10 good location.

**This approach would work most of the time, but sometime this solution still be fooled.**

Code is copied from this [blog](https://blog.hypertrack.com/2017/07/19/hypertrack-detects-mock-locations-android/) .