# How to prevent Fake GPS (Location Spoofing) on Android

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, spoofing

We've read many of posts on Stackoverflow, regarding prevent fake gps.

We're now running kind of social network android application,
and recently launched Pokemon GO-like location based gaming feature.

We were anxious about using fake gps, so I tried to find as many as information on Stackoverflow, but unfortunately managed to find a few. (It seems only a few looked into it - or situation changed. Like some of API deprecated.)

So here's our current situation, can you advice us about how to proceed?

---

- I found some article about wechat, using BaiduLocationSDK. So we adopt it, and now we are using it.
- It successfully blocked many of location spoofing apps, (like "fly gps") but we found the other still working. (like Fake gps go - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.excellentapps.fakegpsgo)
- Fortunately, when we quit the app after setting mock location, it don't persist. (maybe only BaiduLocationSDK can do it)
- But we thought it is not the ideal solution. We tried to make list of fake gps apps and
  A) Detect them and if a user uses it, block him and he can't use our app
  B) Kill the process of them

but A, B doesn't work. (It worked before - about 1~2 month, but It doesn't now.)

---

Please help us proceed.

Comment: Access settings and see if any app is set on location spoofing in developer settings. If any app is listed there, block the usage of GPS

Comment: @LunarWatcher Is it possible to access and see if user is using Mock Location on developer setting? I heard that API is deprecated..

Comment: Probably. Even though the APi is deprecated, it is fine as long as it isn't removed. Haven't really done anything with it ever, it was only a suggestion.

Comment: @GarySeo i believe you are now supposed to use (mylocationprovider).isFromMockProvider() so you can find out directly from the location object instead of querying settings. If it's > a certain API, make a function to check both

Comment: Hi, did you find another solution ?

Comment: @BackPacker some useful thing can be found out here with deep insight here in this already answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880232/disable-check-for-mock-location-prevent-gps-spoofing