# Android: Disable mock location for geofence

Tags: android, geofencing, mock-location

I am developing an Android app purely on geofence.

**Concept:** My basic concept on geofence is user can play games for particular geo location.

**Problem:** Everything is working fine but I downloaded the FakeGPS application from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps). I was at home and I setup my desired location from where I can play game. My application has detected that geo location and I could play that game from my home. Actually it was supposed to play that game only for geo location.

**Solution:** I have checked that location is coming from **MockProvider** or not on `GeofenceIntentService` class by given code.

```
boolean isMockLcoation = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation().isFromMockProvider();
```

But its not a reliable solution. I am not getting every time accurate result.

I have checked `LocationAssistance` service but anyway it couldn't help me for geofence.

**Goal:** I want to either disable mock location for my application or distinguish the location is true or mock.

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to check if mock location setting is enabled. Here is a SO answer just for that, or you can just use the code below, which was from that same answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776891/5318240

```
public static boolean isMockSettingsON(Context context) {
    // returns true if mock location enabled, false if not enabled.
    if (Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0"))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```