# Detect if Mock location (GPS Spoofing) is enabled and request to disable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mocking

Since I tried to make a long search about, I'm trying to detect if some app are listed to use mock location o just simply if Mock location is enabled and not setted to "anyone".

I just want restrict the user to disable mock (if enabled) if u want go forward.

I'm using Xamarin.Android (c#) and reading android development there are no clue to do this. Is that really impossible as it seems?

ALLOW_MOCK is deprecated then how can I afford this on API 29+?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726023/4984832

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually isfrommock is used during the retrieving of GPS while I need to detect it before... Anyway I wasn't able to use it in xamarin.android, actually it isn't recognized as command.